# TOTP creating using bash and HMAC

Tags: linux, bash, hash, modulo, one-time-password

I'm trying to write a bash code that generates 6 digits TOTPs. I wrote the following code:

```
##!/bin/bash
T=`date '+%Y%m%d%H%M'`
K="secret"
prefix="(stdin)= "
keyhex=$(echo -n $T | openssl dgst -sha1 -hmac $K | sed -e "s/^$prefix//")
dec=$((echo $(( 16#$keyhex )) ))
key=$((echo $(($dec % 1000000))))
echo $key
```

Sometimes it works, and sometimes I get the following error:

```
./auth.sh: line 6: echo 4076818289415231324 : syntax error in expression (error token is "4076818289415231324 ")
./auth.sh: line 7: % 1000000: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "% 1000000")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if some answer helps you, kindly consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). That'll contribute reputation to both you and the answerer. Also take the [tour] to understand more how this work

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use `$((arithmetic expansion))` where you should be using `$(command substitution)`:

Instead of

```
dec=$((echo $(( 16#$keyhex )) ))
```

use

```
dec=$(echo $(( 16#$keyhex )) )
```

or even better, just

```
dec=$(( 16#$keyhex ))
```

Here's your script with these and a few other tweaks:

```
#!/bin/bash
T=$(date '+%Y%m%d%H%M')
K="secret"
prefix="(stdin)= "
keyhex=$(printf '%s' "$K" | openssl dgst -sha1 -hmac $K | sed -e "s/^$prefix//")
dec=$(( 16#$keyhex ))
key=$((dec % 1000000))
echo "$key"
```

Comment: Thanks, it works now. However, I get different results running on different machines what could be the reason? Machine 1 echo $BASH_VERSION
4.3.48(1)-release
 Machine 2 echo $BASH_VERSION
4.4.12(1)-release

Comment: At which line do the values start to diverge?

Comment: Nevermind the 2 machines were configured at different time zone now works great thank you so much

Comment: You can use `date -u` to always get UTC time wherever you run the script